# Rename enum fields in match (rust)

Tags: rust, enums, match

I have a match block on enum, and one of it`s match cases contains another match block on the same enum. Something like this:

```
fn foo(&mut self, scenario: &mut Scenario) -> Result<&mut Self>
{
match self {
            Scenario::Step { attributes, .. } => {
                match scenario {
                    Scenario::Step { attributes,.. } => {
```

Is there any way to access both `attributes` field inside of the inner match? I see possibility to just return that field from the inner match block, but can it be handled in more beauty way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rename the matched variable like this:

```
fn foo(&mut self, scenario: &mut Scenario) -> Result<&mut Self>
{
match self {
            Scenario::Step { attributes: attrs1, .. } => {
                match scenario {
                    Scenario::Step { attributes: attrs2,.. } => {
                        // do something with attrs1 and attrs2
```

And even nicer, you could match on them in a tuple:

```
fn foo(&mut self, scenario: &mut Scenario) -> Result<&mut Self>
{
match (self, scenario) {
            (Scenario::Step { attributes: attrs1, .. }, Scenario::Step { attributes: attrs2,.. }) => {
                // do something with attrs1 and attrs2
```

Comment: Also note that you don't have to rename both, you can keep one as just `attributes` without renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

You could match both of them at the same time in a tuple:

```rust
fn foo(&mut self, scenario: &mut Scenario) -> Result<&mut Self> {
    match (self, escenario) {
        (Scenario::Step { attributes, .. }, Scenario::Step { attributes: attributes2, .. }) => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because Rust doesn't know it's supposed to assign `attributes` to `attributes2`. You have to explicitly rename it like `Scenario::Step { attributes: attributes2, .. }`

Comment: @isaactfa, yes, good catch there, thanks!